# Could not initialize com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment

Tags: java, maven, ibm-mq

I've upgraded my maven dependencies for IBM MQ from these(version: 6.0.2.5):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>mq</artifactId>
    <version>${ibm-mq-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>mqjms</artifactId>
    <version>${ibm-mq-version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.disthub2</groupId>
    <artifactId>dhbcore</artifactId>
    <version>DH610-Gold</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>mqetclient</artifactId>
    <version>${ibm-mq-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

To that(version: 7.5.0.5):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>mq-jms-all</artifactId>
    <version>${ibm-mq-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, everytime I try to run my project, I get the following error:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment
```

The maven-dependency is imported correctly and is also visible in Eclipse in the maven-dependencies-tab. Also i see the com.ibm.mq.jar in the classpath.

I've googled a lot and the only real solution, which worked for some people was, to add the connector.jar. But I'm already using the jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
    <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
    <version>${connector-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What repository are you using the get the new MQ JARs from? Do you have the new JARs imported in your local Maven repository?

Comment: @AttilaRepasi It's the nexus repository from my company. Yes the jars are in my local repo.

Comment: The class com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment is in the JAR com.ibm.mq.jar as it comes with the MQ instalaltion. I don't know what this mq-jms-all artifact is, but I think it does not have all the necessary classes from the JARs. I'm using the following JARs from the MQ installation for JMS connection: com.ibm.mqjms.jar, com.ibm.mq.jar com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar, com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar, com.ibm.mq.headers.jar, fscontext.jar, providerutil.jar, dhbcore.jar

Comment: I know. It's added to the path.

Comment: @AttilaRepasi That artifact should contain all necessary files. And I also see the MQEnvironment.class in the jar.

Comment: More details required.  What do you do when you "run your project".  Is it maven test or running application out of maven or IDE?  The jar is not getting loaded.  I will check the classpath if I were you.  Was there any ClassNotFoundException thrown before this exception?

Comment: If you go with the v8.0 client, IBM provides a [jar-only installation](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/doSelectFixes?options.selectedFixes=8.0.0.3-WS-MQ-Install-Java-All&continue=1) that is fully supported.  With all earlier versions of MQ client, installing anything less than the full client runtime is *not* officially supported.

Comment: @Christian, this question keeps getting bumped by community every 4 months because it has no accepted answer, did any of the answers help you or if not can you self answer it so that it won't get bumped, or perhaps let me know and I'll try to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> IBM MQ from these(version: 6.0.2.5):
>
> To that(version: 7.5.0.5):

IBM moved the MQException to the 'com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar' file.

As per the the [MQ Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120070_.htm), you need the following jar files for MQ JMS programming:

- com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar
- com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
- com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
- com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
- connector.jar
- jms.jar
- dhbcore.jar
- rmm.jar
- jndi.jar
- ldap.jar
- fscontext.jar
- providerutil.jar
- CL3Export.jar
- CL3Nonexport.jar

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem and this fixed it

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
    <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
    <version>${connector-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

These are my dependencies.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.commonservices</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.headers</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.1.4</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.1.4</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.soap</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.1.4</version>
</dependency>       

        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.headers</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.1.4</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.pcf</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.1.4</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
  <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
  <artifactId>connector</artifactId>
  <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.dhbcore</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>CL3Nonexport</artifactId>
            <version>${webspheremq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mqetclient</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse (Dynamic Web Project (Servlet)) you need copy  files:

```
com.ibm.mq.commomservices.jar
com.ibm.mq.defaultconfig.jar
com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
com.ibm.mq.jar
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi.jar
com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar
com.ibm.mqetclient.jar
com.ibm.mqjms.jar
connector.jar
dhbcode.jar
fscontext.jar
jms.jar
```

to /WebContext/WEB-INF/lib, then add them into Project (Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path ->  Add External JARs).
 After all, go through these steps:

- close project
- close Eclipse
- open Eclipse
- open project.

Good Luck!